# jQuery Show/Hide currency

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to show only the `.price .amount` (canadian dollar price) on the front end when the page loads. Upon clicking on the "USD", the `.price` will load while hiding the `.price .amount` (canadian dollar price). I cannot apply a class to the USD price in the html markup because it's how the plugin is loading from WordPress.

While USD price is shown, the "CAD" text will show but not the canadian dollar price allowing the visitor to click on it to show the `.price .amount` (canadian dollar price) while hiding the USD price afterwards. So basically I need one to show while the other does not (Canadian price to show on page load at first though).

I'm pretty new to web development so any help would be appreciated

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".price .amount").show();

  $(".CAD").click(function() {
    $(".price").hide();
    $(".price .amount").slideToggle("slow");
  });

  $(".USD").click(function() {
    $(".price .amount").hide();
    $(".price").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="price" style="display: none;">
  <span class="amount" style="display: inline;">
      $ 13,500
  </span>
  <br />
  <span class="newAmount">
      USD 10395.00
  </span>
</p>
<div class="CAD">
  <h1>CAD</h1>
</div>
<div class="USD">
  <h1>USD</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier if the CAD and USD prices were wrapped in their own `<span>` elements (or similar)

Comment: I know lol. But this is how the plugin is spitting out the "Additional currency" next to my default CAD currency. I'll look into the plugin file now.

Comment: It's the Woocommerce Additional Currency

Comment: I went into the plugin and able to change the markup. Now they both have span classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can do something like this:

**HTML**

```
    <p class="price canadianamount" style="">
      <span class="amount canadian" style="display: inline;">
                $ 13,500
            </span>
    </p>
<p class='american'>
            <span class='us'> USD 10395.00 </span>
</p>
    <div class="CAD">
      <h1>CAD</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="USD">
      <h1>USD</h1>
    </div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Keep it in sepaarte `<p>` tags

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.canadianamount,.american').hide();
      $(".CAD").click(function() {
        $(".american").hide();
        $(".canadianamount").slideToggle("slow");
      });

      $(".USD").click(function() {
        $(".canadianamount").hide();
        $(".american").slideToggle("slow");
      });
    });
```

Look at the **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a95vgm2e/)**

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! But thanks to you I went into the plugin to add that span class. Yay!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".price .amount").show();
            $(".price .newAmount").hide();

            $(".CAD").click(function(){
                $(".price .newAmount").hide();
                $(".price .amount").slideToggle("slow");
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            $(".USD").click(function() {
                $(".price .amount").hide();
                $(".price .newAmount").slideToggle("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: plus one ,for finding the solution on your own :)

Comment: Keep in mind that the modifications you have made to the plugin will most likely be lost when/if you update the plugin.